# Android NDK Error. Not able to build the project

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following specified error,

```
E:\SDK\ndk-bundle\build\core\setup-app-platform.mk
```

Error:(115) *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Error:Execution failed for task ':un7zip:compileReleaseNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process E:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=E:\appRizort\RizortCardboard\un7zip\build\intermediates\ndk\release\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-25 NDK_OUT=E:\appRizort\RizortCardboard\un7zip\build\intermediates\ndk\release\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=E:\appRizort\RizortCardboard\un7zip\build\intermediates\ndk\release\lib APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a,armeabi,x86,arm64-v8a}

Comment: NDK does not support **android-25**  platform. You can set **android-24** or (with r15 beta) **android-26**.

Comment: Yes, this thing worked. Thanks. @AlexCohn

Comment: Even with android-26, I get NDK_PROJECT_PATH as null in Android Studio. However, if I run it from command prompt, the build works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Your NDK_PROJECT_PATH is null, if your path to the project folder contains white-space, it may cause this issue.

Comment: There is no whitespace present

Comment: `NDK_PROJECT_PATH` is null when **ndk-build** is run by the gradle Android plugin in Android Studio, it's kosher.

Answer (score 3):

`APP_PLATFORM` that you specify when you build the native part of your project with NDK is very important. The story is [described at length in the NDK guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html):

> This variable contains the minimum Android platform version you want to support. For example, a value of `android-15` specifies that your library uses APIs that are not available below Android 4.0.3 (API level 15) and can't be used on devices running a lower platform version. For a complete list of platform names and corresponding Android system images, see Android [NDK Native APIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html).
>
> Instead of changing this flag directly, you should set the minSdkVersion property in the `defaultConfig` or `productFlavors` blocks of your [module-level build.gradle file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#module-level). This makes sure your library is used only by apps installed on devices running an adequate version of Android. The ndk-build toolchain uses the following logic to choose the minimum platform version for your library based the ABI you're building and the `minSdkVersion` you specify:
>
> 1. If there exists a platform version for the ABI equal to `minSdkVersion`, ndk-build uses that version.
> 2. Otherwise, if there exists platform versions lower than `minSdkVersion` for the ABI, ndk-build uses the highest of those platform versions. This is a reasonable choice because a missing platform version typically means that there were no changes to the native platform APIs since the previous available version.
> 3. Otherwise, ndk-build uses the next available platform version higher than `minSdkVersion`.

NDK does not have separate `android-25` platform. You can choose `android-24` or (with r15 beta), `android-26`, if your minimal supported platform is O. If your `minSdkVersion` is less, or if in doubt, choose lower platform for NDK, because NDK platforms are upwards-compatible.